# What is Uru made of?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

In the MCU, Uru is the material Thor's axe Stormbreaker, (and possibly Mjolnir IIRC), are made of. Is there any indication what this metal is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uru is not a metal per se, it's a metallic ore. Its appearance is stone-like with metallic properties. The ore is primarily sought after for its ability to store energy, particularly magical ones.

It is found and mined only in the Nidavellir realm. It is one of the most prized exports of the dwarven miners that reside there.

You are correct about it being the material used to make both Stormbreaker and Mjolnir. Apparently, it was also used to construct Odin's spear - Gungnir, which he can be seen holding in previous Thor movies. It is said to occur in two variations in terms of appearance.

> The appearance of Uru metal ore is in two forms, one as "metallic gold" (Gungnir, Stormbreaker) and the other as having a luster that has been described as "badly wrought iron" (Mjolnir). When Uru is enchanted, it becomes much more durable.

[Source](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Uru)

Comment: Is these information related to MCU? OP asked information on MCU I think..  Im just saying IMO. The source is for comic books it seems

Comment: There's not a whole lot of information to go with if we stick to MCU. I don't believe Uru was discussed in great detail in any of the movies. Our only option then is to look at the canon. For an in MCU explanation you may want to look at Vishwa's answer.

Comment: There were no Dwarves on Asgard, and no indication that Uru was found there, let alone only there.

Comment: Well the fallacy lies in seeing Asgard as just a planet. It is sort of a planetary system. And Nidavellir (the home of the dwarves) neighbors Asgard. So when I refer to them as Asgardian dwarves, I say that only as a form of association indicating them as close allies of Asgard. I agree, technically it sounds wrong and I'll make that correction. There's more information at the MCU wiki - http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Nine_Realms

Answer (score 6):

From [MCU wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Uru),

> Uru was a godly metal forged in the furnaces of Nidavellir.

Mjolnir, Stormbreaker and also the Infinity Gauntlet were forged using Uru.

Comment: Has Nidavellir any relation to Asgard in MCU? Have they ever mentioned it in the movie?

Comment: It actually does. I don't know if you have seen Infinity Wars, and I don't want to spoil it for you if you haven't. It's been alluded to that they are close allies to Asgard in the movie.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Thanks for the input. I actually didn't get the chance to watch it **properly** yet.. So I've had no idea on Joey's question